# How to enable Ethereum support in the JAXX mobile wallet?

Tags: light-clients, mobile-wallet, jaxx

[Jaxx by Kryptokit](http://jaxx.io/) offers Bitcoin and Ethereum for mobile and browsers.

I installed the wallet on my Android device. But it only offers Bitcoin functionality. I see screenshots online which displays an Ethereum logo which my app does not have.

[image: no eth support] [image: eth support]

How to enable Ethereum support in the JAXX mobile wallet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it's an "easter egg" you have to unlock.

> It has Ethereum integration. Unlock it by tapping the refresh icon twice, then the Jaxx logo Twice. We did an "Easter Egg" contest.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/45kh3n/jaxx_kryptokits_ethereum_android_wallet_is_here/czykhsy).

Answer (score 1):

Tap the "Refresh" button twice and then the "Jaxx" Logo twice. The Ethereum wallet icon will appear beside the bitcoin one.

Bonus: Go to settings to set the Ethereum wallet as the default selection when opening the app.